# Stable vertical alignment of columns in Beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, columns

In Beamer, I often use a two-column slide layout, picture on the left and text on the right. Sometimes the same picture is used on multiple slides, with the text on the right changing. I use the Beamer `columns` environment for this purpose.

My problem is that typically the pictures in the two slides do not have the same vertical alignment, causing a slightly annoying "jiggle". None of the various options for `column` seems to help, and the default (align centers) is the most reasonable anyway.

Is there a way to force the picture to be vertically centered with respect to the page, irrespective of the size of the content of the other column?

Here's an example - the text on the left (representing a picture) moves a little between frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          A figure
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Item 1
              \item Item 2
          \end{itemize}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame 2}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          A figure
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Another item 1
              \item Another item 2
              \item This list is longer
              \item Than the previous one
              \item was
          \end{itemize}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could fix the vertical alignment by using minipages of the same height in the second column. Here's the modified example with a stable left column:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          A figure
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{minipage}[c][.6\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
          \end{minipage}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test frame 2}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          A figure
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          \begin{minipage}[c][.6\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Another item 1
                \item Another item 2
                \item This list is longer
                \item Than the previous one
                \item was
            \end{itemize}
          \end{minipage}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, one more question. Rather than `.6\textheight`, I'd like to use a value which is always large enough (so that I can use this in a macro). It seems that `textheight` is too large; does Beamer have a variable that stores the height of the text area of the slide?

Comment: I guess it's `\beamer@frametextheight` in beamerbaseframe.sty.

Comment: Thanks! For the benefit of those not used to @ (which is special), you can use the following sequence to define a `\frametextheight`, which you can then use in place of `.6\textheight` in the above.


`\makeatletter\let\frametextheight\beamer@frametextheight\makeatother`

Answer (score 97):

I had similar problem and found out that it is enough to start the `columns` environment command by `[T]` options,

```
\begin{columns}[T]
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: This forces same alignment for all columns, not individually.

Comment: Should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 23):

It is also possible to center contents of columns vertically with the `[c]` options. It works fine for me. Maybe this helps also to solve your problem.

```
\begin{columns}[c]
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a good candidate for the `overprint` environment. It typesets different material on different slides, but puts them all inside a box the size of the largest one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<1>{Test frame}
    \frametitle<2>{Test frame 2}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
          A figure
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{overprint}
          \onslide<1>
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Item 1
              \item Item 2
          \end{itemize}
          \onslide<2>
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Another item 1
              \item Another item 2
              \item This list is longer
              \item Than the previous one
              \item was
          \end{itemize}
        \end{overprint}
      \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** although, I just realized that this makes both lists be top-aligned, so the shorter one may look a bit displaced. I'm not sure if there's a way to specify that the contents of `overprint` should be vertically centered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For various reasons I prefer to keep the frames separate, but that's interesting that you can use overlays with `frametitle`, I didn't know that!