# Layout issues with beamerposter

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I am having some layout issues with `beamerposter`. As you can see the vertical alignment does not work properly. Also, the conclusions block is too long.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Berlin}
}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=200,height=120,scale=2.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{} 

  \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth]

    %% 1 column
    \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Problem}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    %% 2 column
    \begin{column}{0.63\textwidth}

      \begin{columns}[totalwidth = \textwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
          \begin{block}{Column 1}
          \end{block}           
        \end{column}       
        %% 
        \begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
          \begin{block}{Column 2}
          \end{block}
        \end{column}     
      \end{columns}

      \begin{block}{Conclusion}
      \end{block}

    \end{column}

  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the vertical alignment, you can use the [t] option (or [T] to force it) (see a related question and its second answer, [Stable vertical alignment of columns in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/stable-vertical-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer))

As for the second point, it is, I think, a problem with the horizontal centering of columns. It may vary from one theme to another (see this answer [How to center blocks and columns in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59974/how-to-center-blocks-and-columns-in-beamer)). For instance, using the `default`, the `CambridgeUS` or the `PaloAlto` theme, this problem seems to disappear. I guess you would have to try and find another theme that does not cause this issue and suits you.

Here is the code that sorts out the first issue :

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Berlin}
}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=200,height=120,scale=2.4,debug]{beamerposter}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{} 

  \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth,t]

    %% 1 column
    \begin{column}{0.32\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Problem}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    %% 2 column
    \begin{column}{0.63\textwidth}

      \begin{columns}[totalwidth = \textwidth]
       \begin{column}{0.47\linewidth}
          \begin{block}{Column 1}
          \end{block}           
        \end{column}       
        %% 
        \begin{column}{0.47\linewidth}
          \begin{block}{Column 2}
          \end{block}
        \end{column}     
      \end{columns}

      \begin{block}{Conclusion}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will wait another day and then award the bounty to you.