# Beamer: text in one column, overlayed pictures in second column

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I know similar questions have been asked in this forum and I've read many threads about it, but I cannot get it working like I want it to.

I have a slide with some text in the left column. Then I want to insert the first picture in the right (with a click) and after the next click I want the second picture appear in the same spot (right column) while the first one disappears.

Now I got that working with `\visible` but I get the problem that the text is moving downwards when clicking.

I tried `\onslide` and `\only` as well with different options like `<1>` and `<1->` but neither worked out.

Here's some example:

```
\frame{ %
%
\frametitle{Frametitle}


\begin{columns}

  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \textbf{bold text} \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item text1
        \item text2
        \item an equation
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

\pause

  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
          \visible<2>{
          \includegraphics<2>[width=.7\textwidth]{image1.png}
          } \pause
          %----
          \visible<3>{
          \includegraphics<3>[width=.7\textwidth]{image2.png}
          }
      \end{center}
  \end{column}

\end{columns}
}
```

Would appreciate your help - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An `overlayarea` can help - or you avoid the problem in the first place by using a top aligned frame with `\begin{frame}[t]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frametitle}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
            \textbf{bold text}\\
            \begin{itemize}
                \item text1
                \item text2
                \item an equation
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{5cm}
                    \includegraphics<2>[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                    \includegraphics<3>[width=.7\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-b}
                \end{overlayarea}
            \end{center}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that works as well, but poses the same problem, I described in my own answer: I cannot get the image as large as I'd like to. As for aligning the whole frame at the top: I think that doesn't look as good.

Comment: @Robert Did you try to adjust the value of `5cm` to the height of your largest image?

Comment: Yes, but that only changed the height without scaling the width correctly. I finally used the solution, I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Phuu, I finally got it... and I have multiple thoughts on this topic for anyone who gets into the same trouble.

**First:** if one doesn't need the figure to be too big, you can just adjust the parameters of the columns and the figuresize. When I used 0.65 for the graphics width, it did the job and I also modified the column sizes such that it doesn't quite add up to one (e.g. 0.35 and 0.6)
What I am taking out of that: Latex seems to be unable to put oversized boxes or environments correctly on a slide/page, that possibly exceed the boundaries of the text box.
Probably no proper latex-syntax talking, but I hope you get what I mean.

**Second:** As I did want the figure as large as possible, I used minipages like in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/stable-vertical-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer).
I don't really like the somewhat redundant use of columns and minipages but it worked out.

It looks like this at the end:

```
\frame{ % Optik und Optomechanik
%
\frametitle{Optik und Optomechanik}


\begin{columns}

\onslide<1->{
\begin{column}[T]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[c][.6\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
    \textbf{bold text} \\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item text1
        \item text2
        \item more text
    \end{itemize} 
    \end{minipage}}
\end{column}

\begin{column}[T]{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[c][.6\textheight][c]{1.1\linewidth}
    \centering{\includegraphics<2>[width=.7\textwidth]{image1.png}}%
    %----
    %\centering{\includegraphics<3>[width=.7\textwidth]{image1.png}} %if necessary
    \end{minipage}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
}
```

And of course, you can always mess around with the scales and sizes...
Have fun!

Comment: I'm curious, what do you mean by "correctly" exactly?

Comment: Good question. "Correctly" is definitely not the best word. I meant: it should rather ignore the boundaries of the textbox than squeeze oversize objects together... But of course one has to declare that...